# Script in a page, stopped working while Including content from other page with different script

Tags: javascript, laravel, include

I am using **Laravel 5** .
I am trying to include different content in a page using:

```
@include('example_page_content_one') 
@include('example_page_content_two')
```

Every page i am including has its own script.

```
@section('script')
  <script>
  </script>
@endsection
```

While browsing **parent** page, where all content pages were included, only script in **example_page_content_two** page is working and **other scripts**  both in **parent** and **example_page_content_one** are not working.

I am extending `master.blade.php` in **parent** page.
In master page i used

```
@yield('script')
```

Is there any way to solve this without using different **section** name. 
i.e

In **example_page_content_one**

```
@section('scriptExampleOne')@endsection
```

In **example_page_content_two**

```
@section('scriptExampleTwo')@endsection
```

In master blade

```
   @yield('scriptExampleOne')
   @yield('scriptExampleTwo')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `@append` to end your script.  If you use `@endsection` then it will overwrite any previously added content.

So:

```
@section('script')
     <script>
     </script>
@append
```

Comment: Its working for script!! when i tried this in main content only the content of last @included page showing. How to solve this?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand.  If you are using `@include` then you do not need `@section` for the content, only if you need to add something to a different section than where you are including - if that makes sense.